# Why are there no true oneway mirrors?

Tags: reflection

"[One way mirrors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror)" are used in interrogation rooms etc. The wikipedia article states that:

> A true one way mirror does not, and cannot, exist. Light always
>   passes exactly equally in both directions. However, when one side is
>   brightly lit and the other kept dark, the darker side becomes
>   difficult to see from the brightly lit side because it is masked by
>   the much brighter reflection of the lit side.

Which I think I understand. 
What I find strange is that this surely can't be any deep principle of physics, as it's easily "violated"; you could just place a camera on one side and a TV on the other side, and it would be perfectly "see-through" from one side but not the other.

Couldn't you imagine a sort of microscopic version of the above "violation"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is one way glass possible?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19043/)

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101380/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92301/

Comment: See the duplicate Kyle suggests. A true oneway mirror could be used to make a perpetual motion device because it could be used to make heat flow from a cold area to a hot area.